# android popupwindow float outside of parent view

Tags: android

Instead of dismissing a popup, I would like to hide it off screen at position -width,-heigt.  When I try to update the popup off screen it gets stopped at the bounds of the parent view. How do I update it off screen, or semi offscreen?

```
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.mylayout,null);
    pop = new PopupWindow(this);
    pop.setTouchable(false);
    pop.setHeight(200);
    pop.setWidth(200);
    pop.setContentView(view);
    pop.showAtLocation(myparentview, 0, 50, 50);    
    pop.update(-200,-200,-1,-1);
```

Snapshot of problem:
[image: won't pass 0,0]

Comment: This code works perfectly for me on Android ICS, try to change anchor view and use this method: public void update (View anchor, int xoff, int yoff, int width, int height)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you are missing is using the `setClippingEnabled` with `false`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setClippingEnabled(boolean)

You should call it before the `update()` call and this should let you paint the window outside screen bounderies.

Answer (score 0):

i don't sure but dear try this.

apply the popwindow width and height according the device as you use.
like here you apply **200*200**.
just apply this height and width runtime.